# Any fork of previous Jasper Studio or eclipse plugin source code?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jaspersoft-studio, jasper-plugin

The later version of JasperStudio  being now closed source, since the licensing of previous versions of JasperStudio and the eclipse plugin required the source code to be freely available, did someone has this source code and maybe already forked the source for one or  both products?

I would gladly contribute to such fork if they exist (Obviously we need the code for this but I can't find it)

If not, what are the viable FOSS alernatives for JasperStudio and also the eclipse plugin?

Thx

Comment: I don't JasperStudio, maybe [Eclipse BIRT](http://eclipse.org/birt) is an alternative. This kind of questions are better asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/